# Batch Comparative Statement breakdown

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, goto

I have a selection menu that for some reason is breaking down.  The code:

```
: uninstallerMenu
echo REMOVE ME!  total items %count%
set uninstallNr=
set /P uninstallNr=Please select a number:  
echo %uninstallNr%
if /I %uninstallNr% LEQ %count% goto uninstaller
if /I '%uninstallNr%'=='M' goto menu
:: Uninstaller Error Handler
: uninstallerError
cls
echo.
echo ==================== INVALID INPUT ====================
echo _______________________________________________________
echo.
echo    Please select a number or 'M' to go to Main Menu
echo _______________________________________________________
echo.
echo ============== PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE ==============
pause>null
cls
if '%opt%'=='64' goto progList64
if '%opt%'=='32' goto progList32
goto menu
```

The problem resides in the less than or equal to check. If I put %uninstallRn% LEQ %count% it will check it and send it to uninstaller if it's true, and pressing the M key does what it's supposed to do, but pressing the enter key breaks the script.

Now if I add

```
if '%uninstallNr%'=='' goto uninstallerError
```

before

```
if /I %uninstallNr% LEQ %count% goto uninstaller
if /I '%uninstallNr%'=='M' goto menu
```

Then everything goes to the uninstallerError section?!?!  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should replace all single quotes with double quotes and try again.

Comment: this works in about a dozen other scripts with single quotes, I think it has something to do with the LEQ statement, but not sure how that's affecting it.  Because if I take that out everything works fine (except I have no way of testing the numbers then)

Comment: this doesn't work: `if '%uninstallNr%'=='' goto uninstallerError`. It's nonsense.

Comment: yeah, it needed to have quotes removed all together, if you look at other coding structures it makes sense, it just doesn't work in this application of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few problems.

Possibly

```
if not defined uninstallnr goto wherever
```

is better than the quoted version. YMMV.

Second, if you use `IF /I` then the comparison is made character-by-character, so '12' is less than '2' because '1' is less than '2'

And third, batch simply charges right on through labels, so if your IF statements don't GOTO anywhere because the condition wasn't true, then batch will simply continue over the `:uninstallerError` label - which may NOT include a space, by the way,,,at least, if you're going to use it as a destination for a `GOTO` (or `CALL` for that matter)

Oh - and double-quotes are the way to define a string. Using single quotes or `[]` only works when the variable DOESN'T contain spaces (and a few other characters)

Also, it's not `null`, it's `nul` (you'd create a file called `null`)

---

AIUI, your current code is

```
SETLOCAL
SET count=3
set uninstallNr=
set /P uninstallNr=Please select a number:  
echo %uninstallNr%
if '%uninstallNr%'=='' goto uninstallerError
if /I %uninstallNr% LEQ %count% goto uninstaller
if /I '%uninstallNr%'=='M' goto menu
:: Uninstaller Error Handler
:uninstallerError
ECHO AT uninstallererror
GOTO :eof
:uninstaller
ECHO AT uninstaller
GOTO :eof
:menu
ECHO AT menu
GOTO :eof
```

Or similar.

I've set COUNT inline.

Entry of 1,2 or 3 goes happily to UNINSTALLER. m to Menu and otherwise to UNINSTALLERROR.

(consider an entry of '0' while you're at it... but that's a side-issue...)

Comment: Originally the goal was that if you hit enter then you didn't meet the requirement of being less than the total menu count or pressing M thus going to the error prompt, which also meant that if you put any number more than the counter you also went to it, the only reason i added that label was to skip to it when the thing wasn't working.  This works everywhere else except here, once I added that LEQ statement the entire thing fell apart.

Comment: ok, i added if not defined %uninstallNr% goto uninstallerError under the goto menu part and it still isn't working, I did notice something though, I'm getting an error saying that %count% is where it's breaking.  The count in this instance is 9 items, it's saying "9 was unexpected at this time"

Comment: ok, i'm dumb, no % before and after the variable:  
if not defined uninstallNr goto uninstallerError

Comment: meh - happens to all of us.